# How can I get the same emacs experience on any computer?

Tags: init-file, remote, config

I really enjoy my emacs config (the `autocomplete` and indentation settings, the use of things like `jedi` and `tern` etc.)

Most of the time I use emacs at home on my personal macbook pro laptop but I am wondering if there is a way I could make my system more portable.  I already store my `.emacs.d` on github, but my dream is that I could go to any computer in the world and somehow recreate my experience.

It is strange because even when I have cloned my repo into a remote machine and ssh'd into that remote machine, most things are completely different.

Beginning with the theme, my understanding is that this has something to do with the way the host (computer I am on) terminal is setup.  For instance it might not support colors.

But, should autocomplete drop downs like those for tern and jedi still work when I am ssh'd in?

I would very much appreciate any suggestions on how I could best recreate my emacs experience on a remote machine.

Thank

Comment: Are you using the Emacs version/setup on the remote machine and wondering why that version/setup is not the same as the local machine?  If so, perhaps it is because they are not the same version/setup.  Are you asking instead how to modify the Emacs version/setup on the remote machine?  Perhaps others will be clear as to what you are asking, but I am left trying to guess.   Perhaps you are interested in using Tramp so that you can use your local Emacs version/setup [that way you are not calling the Emacs version/setup on the remote machine]?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. to clarify, what I'm after, is being able to use an identical emacs setup regardless of the Computer I am on. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to set up emacs as I like it on a virtual machine and then SSH into that. However, it does not seem like the various tools (ie tern.js) work in this scenario

Comment: Is using Emacs/Tramp on your local machine not an option for you?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode  If you have all the necessary privileges, it is certainly possible to install Emacs on the remote machine with the same setup you are accustomed to; however, that is lots of extra leg-work -- you will want to very the Emacs version with `M-x emacs-version` and verify your setup is being used.  If they look and smell different, it is probably because they are different.  You might wish to start by calling your new Emacs installation with the absolute path to the executable.

Comment: That will work but not when I go to work and have to use a different computer.

Comment: What exactly "not work" when using TRAMP on different machines?

Comment: Because I would be using a different computer, my `emacs.d` folder would not be present there so my custom functionality is what would "not work"

Comment: (Disclaimer: I haven't tried this) Maybe you can try the suggestion in: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352367/is-it-possible-to-start-emacs-using-a-remote-configuration-file* along with using: *gitfs (https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs)?*

Comment: Isn't `tern` an external depedency? Maybe `jedi` as well? If you don't have your dependencies installed on the machine Emacs is running on, you can hardly expect Emacs to see them. Chances are that the best that your config can do in the absence of such things is to refrain from throwing errors unless you attempt to *use* the features in question.

Comment: As far as the actual Emacs configuration goes, it's my opinion that managing your config in version control (particularly all the elisp libraries and elpa packages) is the best way to ensure you have the same configuration on any computer. It sounds like you're doing this already, and your issues are environmental, in which case tackling the discrepancies one at a time is probably all that you can do. If you will be using different versions of Emacs on different machines, it is up to you to ensure that your config is compatible with all the versions you'll be using.